# how to fix a gradient background?

Tags: html, css, styles, gradient, styling

i would like to know if it is possible to fix a gradient that comes from html tag:

```
html, body, .wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
body > .wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

html {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-attachment: fixed !important;
    background-image: green;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(green), color-stop(20%, #fff), color-stop(80%, #fff), color-stop(100%, green));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, green, #fff 20%, green 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, green, #fff 20%, green 100%));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, green, #fff 20%, green 100%));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, green, #fff 20%, green 100%));
    background-image: linear-gradient(left, green, #fff 20%, green 100%));

}
```

so that when you will resize the browser window that the gradient does not move.

is this possible?

thanks alot.

Comment: you have extra close brackets `)` at the end of your gradient definitions. such a small thing... =)

Comment: Also, you're setting `background-image` to `green` as a fallback. It should be `background-color`.

Comment: typo! real code is different to that example. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set it to a specific px value:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, green 0%, #fff 300px, green 100%);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GuMKd/

Consider using this tool: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/